# react-native-webview how to inject javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-webview

On Android, I had been using [expo-stripe-checkout](https://github.com/briansztamfater/expo-stripe-checkout) for payments on an Expo managed app. Everything was working fine until I updated to the newest version of expo and react-native. Now, none of the callbacks, like onClose and onPaymentSuccess are working. It seems WebView was removed from react-native, so I'm importing directly from `react-native-webview`.

Instead of using `expo-stripe-checkout`, I created my own component, to try and work through what's happening, and it seems as if WebView's `injectedJavaScript` isn't running at all, and therefore `window.postMessage` or `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` isn't working.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^37.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "prettier": "./node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --print-width 100 --write 'app/**/*.js' -l"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.6.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.18",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "emoji-utils": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.0",
    "expo-analytics": "^1.0.9",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-blur": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-branch": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.8.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-animate-number": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-branch": "4.2.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.20.0",
    "react-native-circular-action-menu": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "0.13.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-invertible-scroll-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-scroll-into-view": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
    "react-native-svg-icon": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.8.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^4.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "~2.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried several different suggestions from around the web, but nothing has worked:

StripeCheckout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

class StripeCheckout extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      publicKey,
      amount,
      allowRememberMe,
      currency,
      description,
      imageUrl,
      storeName,
      prepopulatedEmail,
      style,
      onPaymentSuccess,
      onClose
    } = this.props;

    const jsCode = `(function() {
                    console.log('hello')
                    var originalPostMessage = window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage;
                    var patchedPostMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer) {
                      originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
                    };
                    patchedPostMessage.toString = function() {
                      return String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace('hasOwnProperty', 'postMessage');
                    };
                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage = patchedPostMessage;
                  })();`;
    const runFirst = `
      console.log('firstRun')
      window.isNativeApp = true;
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;

    return (
      <WebView
        ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScriptForMainFrameOnly={false}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        bounces={false}
        messagingEnabled={true}
        onMessage={(event) => console.log(event)}
        onPaymentSuccess(event.nativeEvent.data)}
        injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={runFirst}
        injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
        source={{ html: `<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
            <script>
            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
              key: '${publicKey}',
              image: '${imageUrl}',
              locale: 'auto',
              token: function(token) {
                window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(token.id, token.id);
              },
            });
            window.onload = function() {
              console.log('onload')
              handler.open({
                image: '${imageUrl}',
                name: '${storeName}',
                description: '${description}',
                amount: ${amount},
                currency: '${currency}',
                allowRememberMe: ${allowRememberMe},
                email: '${prepopulatedEmail}',
                closed: function() {
                  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("WINDOW_CLOSED", "*");
                }
              });
            };
            </script>`}}
        style={[{ flex: 1 }, style]}
        scalesPageToFit={Platform.OS === 'android'}
      />
    );
  }
}

StripeCheckout.propTypes = {
  publicKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  storeName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  allowRememberMe: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  onPaymentSuccess: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  currency: PropTypes.string,
  prepopulatedEmail: PropTypes.string,
  style: ViewPropTypes.object
};

StripeCheckout.defaultProps = {
  prepopulatedEmail: '',
  currency: 'USD',
};

export default StripeCheckout;
```

None of the console's are logging. The stripe integration pops up and returns a token successfully, but then nothing happens, and the component isn't receiving the token (i can see it's returning a token from the stripe logs).

Let me know if there's anything else I should post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject js like this way:

```
   const jsCode = `document.querySelector('.HeaderHero').style.backgroundColor = 'purple';`;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={ref => {
            this.webview = ref;
          }}
          source={{ uri: this.state.webViewUrl }}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

for more options take a look: [Medium: Injecting JavaScript into React Native Webview](https://idanlevi2.medium.com/injecting-javascript-into-react-native-webview-521e4e55964b)

Answer (score 0):

A few things off the top of my head:

1. In your package.json, react-native version should be `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",` (Expo SDK 37 is already based on 0.61.4, but with Expo-specific mods). Getting expo-stripe-checkout working as before in previous versions may be as simple as this. [The SDK 37 announcement blog post](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-dd5770f066a6) gives more info on the SDK upgrade process, namely:

   > - Run `expo upgrade` in your project directory (requires the latest version of expo-cli, you can update with `npm i -g expo-cli`).
   > - Make sure to check the changelog for other breaking changes!
   > - ...
2. If that doesn't help to get `expo-checkout-stripe` working again (fix your React Native version anyway, you're bound to have more issues with Expo if you don't), try one or both of the following with your webview:

   - Use `injectJavaScript` as per (Guide > Communicating between JS and Native > The injectJavaScript method)[https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-injectjavascript-method"]. In your case, that would be something like
     `this.webview.injectJavaScript(jsCode)`
   - Spitballing even more than the previous suggestions, but possibly try wrapping your webview's script tags in html/head/body tags. More due diligence/eliminating variables than anything else.

I hope one of these suggestions at least gets you on the right path.